# Viewing a specific process in the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, monitoring

Have been using Ubuntu for about 2 weeks right now and I am in love with it. The only thing I was wondering if it is possible to view the percentage on a process in the terminal, sounds a bit vague but Ill explain it.

Every 2 days I am backing up my system by simply using the terminal. I know I can view my active services by simply typing "top". I notice that the service called gzip is currently active, which is (if I am not mistaken) the service needed for compressing the back up. I was wondering if I could select that service so that it shows me the approximate time needed and the percentage completed.

I don't know if it is possible, maybe that the service doesn't know the actual size of the back up being made or anything else, but I was simply wondering if there is something to monitor this. Could be coming handy for moving big files between HD's.

Comment: `gzip` is not a backup service, it is only a compression program that your real backup service likely uses.

Comment: @grawity Thx! I changed my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: NO

`gzip` is simply a compression program, not a service in any way. It is equivalent to `winzip` (though it uses a different compression algorithm). `gzip` offers no option to track the completion of the process. As a general rule, on *nix you can see the manual for a command by running `man COMMAND`, for example `man gzip`.

Now, a better way to do what you are attempting is to use [`rsync`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/) for your backups which *is* designed for backing up data. `rsync` will not create a compressed archive but it can dynamically compress a file while it is being transferred and so dramatically speed up transfer rates:

```
rsync -azv --progress /files/to/backup /path/to/destination
```

OPTIONS:

```
    -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
    -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
    -z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
        --progress              show progress during transfer

 -a option does the following:

Recursive mode
Preserves symbolic links
Preserves permissions
Preserves timestamp
Preserves owner and group
```

---

You may also be interested in tools that can automate all this like [`mintbackup`](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/install-mintbackup-linux-mint-backup.html)

Comment: Ahh thx! Is there also a way to exclude files that you have in the folder which you are backing up? So for instance "--exclude=/media"

Comment: Yes, `rsync` can do _everything_. Have a look through the link I posted or `man rsync`, the option you are looking for is `--exclude=media`.

Comment: gzip uses the exact same "DEFLATE" algorithm as WinZip.

Comment: @grawity really? I thought winzip used the same algorithm as `zip` which is different from `gzip`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Lossless) seems to agree with me, stating that `Zip` is based on the LZR algorithm while `gzip` uses DEFLATE, a variation of LZ.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, really, to the point that you can use `gunzip` to extract a file from a .zip archive (although only the first one, since that's how gunzip always works). But on the other hand, Zip archives support several compression methods, some old and out-of-use (e.g. Reduce and Implode), some newer (bzip2 or PPMd) – see [APPNOTE.TXT](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) § 4.4.5 which is the official format description. However, Deflate is the most common one. [zlib's website](http://www.zlib.net/) also confirms this.